# Why is my table's content being updated but my sort and pagination aren't?

Tags: angular

I have two `Angular Material` tables displayed in two different tabs. Whenever my view is initialized, the first tab's table is populated with content via a service (the sorting and pagination work correctly on this one). Then, I have a button that after being pressed, creates a few objects and populates the second table successfully. The problem here is that the second table's sorting and pagination features aren't working.

Something I noticed while debugging is that the second table's `sort` element has a `sortable` attribute that has all the first table's columns which have `mat-sort-header` defined. I don't understand why this is happening.

I have two functions to set both table's content, sorting and pagination but even though those functions are equal, only the first table's function is working.

This is my code:

**MyComponent.component.ts**

```
private displayedColumnsRequests = ['edit', 'request_prod_sku', 'request_prod_qty', 'request_indication', 'action'];
private displayedColumnsOrders = ['check', 'prod_sku', 'prod_net_price_eur', 'disc_value_eur', 'prod_price_eur', 'quantity', 'prod_total'];

private dataSourceOrders = new MatTableDataSource(this.orders);
private dataSourceRequests = new MatTableDataSource(this.requests);

@ViewChild(MatSort) ordersSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatSort) requestsSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) ordersPaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) requestsPaginator: MatPaginator;

constructor(private requestsService: RequestsService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.requestsService.currentOrders.subscribe(orderData => this.setOrdersArray(orderData));
 this.requestsService.currentProductsWithIndicationToCreate.subscribe(indicationData => {
      this.setProductsWithIndication(indicationData);
    });

  this.setSecondTableDataSource();
  this.setFirstTableDataSource(); // This one is working as intended
  }

private setOrdersArray(el) {
  this.orders = [];
  for (let key in el) {
    el[key].checked = false;
    el[key].selectedQuantity = 1;
    this.orders.push(el[key]);
  }
}

private setFirstTableDataSource() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSourceOrders = new MatTableDataSource(this.orders);
    this.dataSourceOrders.sort = this.ordersSort;
    this.dataSourceOrders.paginator = this.ordersPaginator;
  });
}

private setSecondTableDataSource() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.dataSourceRequests = new MatTableDataSource(this.requests);
    this.dataSourceRequests.sort = this.requestsSort;
    this.dataSourceRequests.paginator = this.requestsPaginator;
  });
}

onButtonPress() {
  let req = new Request();
  req.request_order_id = 12345;
  req.request_prod_qty = 1;
  req.request_indication = "Refund";
  req["edit"] = false;
  this.requests.push(req);
  this.setSecondTableDataSource();
}
```

**MyComponent.component.html**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="1st Tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceOrders" matSort>
         ........... Table Data ............
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsOrders"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsOrders;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator #ordersPaginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="2nd Tab">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceRequests" matSort>
         ........... Table Data ............
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsRequests"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsRequests;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator #requestsPaginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<button class="btn btn-primary confirm-request-btn" type="button" id="confirm-request-btn-id" (click)="onButtonPress()"> Confirm </button>
```

The scenario that I'm looking for is this: 1. Initialize view; 2. Show first tab with first table with ability to sort and paginate table; 3. Press button; 4. Show second tab with second table with the ability to sort and paginate table.

The scenario I'm currently getting is right until the 4th step because the second table's sort and paginator aren't working.